# MapBox example throws error - mbtiles

Tags: ios, dictionary, offline, mapbox

I am using MapBox example and I have imported my own mbtiles file. I am getting this error: "MB Example[8517:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'.
The default mbtiles file is working fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You are likely not properly bundling the MBTiles file with your app. Be sure that it is added to your app target and is part of the *Copy Bundle Resources* build phase so that it gets copied into the app. Compare to the default as a reference.