# Mapbox show Exception and terminate when using mbtiles in ios

Tags: ios, mapbox

I am using MapBox example and I have imported my mbtiles file. I am getting this error:

> MB Example[8517:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL
>   initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

I have checked my mbtile file and its loading on x-code so there no problem with it.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20531295/2245407

Answer (score 3):

`RMMBTilesSource` is indeed using that code. You need to make sure that your `OSMBright.mbtiles` file is part of the project's target and being added to your bundle so that it can be pulled up as a tile source. Like any resource that you need to use in your app, it's not enough to simply be part of the Xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the crash is clear from your question itself. **reason : [NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter.** You are initializing NSURL without passing a nil parameter. Search for  `initFileURLWithPath` and check wether the parameter is nil or not

```
 [NSURL initFileURLWithPath:] // Pass a valid path here
```

Comment: RMMBTilesSource *offlinesource=[[RMMBTilesSource alloc]initWithTileSetResource:@"OSMBright" ofType:@"mbtiles"]; this is one line of code that is creating exception

Comment: may be RMMBTilesSource using that code. Press cmd+shift+F in xcode then search for that string

Answer (score 0):

Your question cannot be answered correctly in it's current format. You need to add the code related to the issue.

The issue is you are passing a nil parameter to the `initFileURLWithPath` method.

Possibly the `mbtiles` file is missing. So it'll `return nil`, also issue can be in the Mapbox.

Please check that you added it to the project correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error. Are you sure you copied the MapBox.bundle from the .framework into your Xcode-Project as stated here:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/

?
That fixed it for me!